# Remove specific character from a csv file, and rewrite to a new file

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, output, writer

I have a VBA macro pulling stock data every 5 minutes on the entire NYSE. This pulls everything from current price, to earnings dates, to p/e, among other metrics. I'm now trying to set up a cronjob to run a little python code to clean up the csv data before I import it into the mySQL database. Before I can set up the cronjob, I need to get the python code working... Baby steps :).

I went away from python a few years ago, but am trying to use it again here. After some research, it's been vetted that back in 2.6 they removed many of the string methods, followed by the maketrans() argument in 3.1. I'm running python 3.3.

Does anyone have any suggestions for my code below? I'm pulling in 1 line of the csv file at a time, and trying to replace the percent sign (%), with nothing (''). I've tried using the replace() argument within an if statement, but that's not working either. Many, many thanks in advance.

Thanks,

Dan

```
import csv
import string

input_file = open('StockData.csv', 'r')
output_file = open('Output.csv', 'w')
data = csv.reader(input_file)
writer = csv.writer(output_file)
specials = '%'

for line in data:
    trans = s.makestrans(specials, ''*len(specials))
    new_line = line.translate(trans)
    writer.writerow(new_line)

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Comment: You should tag this question with the programming language you're using.

Comment: Have you tried using [string.replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)?  So, `new_line = string.replace(line, '%', '')`

Comment: what's "s" in your code? what happens when you try using replace?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DCLaptop\Desktop\testreplacement.py", line 12, in <module>
    new_line = string.replace(line, '%', '')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: I've tried the replace, it won't work. Keeps saying module object does not have the attribute, 'replace'. This is part of my big dilemma. And sorry Ben, it was to say "str.maketrans(specials, ''*len(specials))'.

Comment: Tried using str.replace(line, '%', '') as well -- here's that error.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DCLaptop\Desktop\testreplacement.py", line 13, in <module>
    new_line = str.replace(line, '%', '')
TypeError: descriptor 'replace' requires a 'str' object but received a 'list'`

Comment: Added code and it runs, now... but still not receiving the correct results.

`for line in data:
    line = str(line)
    new_line = str.replace(line, '%', '')
    writer.writerow(new_line)`

it runs, and writes to a new csv, however every letter is now in it's own cell in the document. Hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help from everyone - below is the code that I got to receive my result. I used help(string.split) in order to get my data to appear in the correct columns after the replacement. Also, the key was making line a string, in order to do the replacement.

```
import csv
import string

input_file = open('DesktopData.csv', 'r')
output_file = open('fixformat.csv', 'w')
data = csv.reader(input_file)
writer = csv.writer(output_file,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)# dialect='excel')
specials = '%'

for line in data:
    line = str(line)
    new_line = str.replace(line,specials,'')
    writer.writerow(new_line.split(','))

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. This solution generates additional Symbols like quotings even if i turn quotings off.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old one, but I've been struggling with a similar problem.

Instead of turning each row into a string so that you can use replace, you can use a list comprehension.

So:

```
for line in data:
    line = str(line)
    new_line = str.replace(line,specials,'')
    writer.writerow(new_line.split(','))
```

becomes:

```
for line in data:
    line = [value.replace(specials, '') for value in line]
    writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Note: this change applies to the answer that is now located below this one, due to this getting more votes, not the original code.