# Python: How to remove $ character from list after CSV import

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am attempting to import a CSV file into Python. After importing the CSV, I want to take an every of every ['Spent Past 6 Months'] value, however the "$" symbol that the CSV includes in front of that value is causing me problems. I've tried a number of things to get rid of that symbol and I'm honestly lost at this point!

I'm really new to Python, so I apologize if there is something very simple here that I am missing.

What I have coded is listed below. My output is listed first:

```
      File "customer_regex2.py", line 24, in <module>
        top20Cust = top20P(data)
      File "customer_regex2.py", line 15, in top20P
        data1 += data1 + int(a[i]['Spent Past 6 Months'])
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '$2099.83'
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOc0g.png)

```
    import csv
    import re
    data = []

    with open('customerData.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
          data.append(row)

    def top20P(a):
      outputList=[]
      data1=0

      for i in range(0,len(a)):
        data1 += data1 + int(a[i]['Spent Past 6 Months'])
      top20val= int(data1*0.8)

      for j in range(0,len(a)):
        if data[j]['Spent Past 6 Months'] >= top20val:
          outputList.append('a[j]')

      return outputList

    top20Cust = top20P(data)
    print(outputList)
```

Comment: Here is a similar problem, you may find solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176542/remove-specific-character-from-a-csv-file-and-rewrite-to-a-new-file

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a datatype issue.

You could strip the $ characters like so:

```py
someString = '$2099.83'
someString = someString.strip('$')
print(someString)
2099.83
```

Now the last step is to wrap in float() since you have decimal values.

```py
print(type(someString))
<class 'str'>

someFloat = float(someString)

print(type(someFloat))
<class 'float'>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had attempted to use .strip() previously, but receive an error as that value is only one of many values within the list. The specific error I received was that type “list” does not contain attribute .strip(), if I recall correctly.  

I’ve found how to remove items from a list using .remove(), as well, but not how to remove only a portion of an item from an item from a list.

Comment: Did you manage to get `.strip('$')` working following the above example? If not, please provide a minimum example of your data. You could use a regular expression to filter for numbers only